# Create the sums of all possible combinations of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have been trying to create a program that is supposed to find all the possible combinations of numbers in a vector, and add them together, then at the end check if they match a given number. I do not want to find EVERY number that add up to a specific number, but rather the sum of the possible combinations. There are many versions of this question already, but I have managed to make the answers suit my problem.

I have tried a recursive version, this one:

```
vector<int> set = {2,3,4,2};
vector<int> allPossible;
vector<int> onePossible = {};
int sum = 0;

void recursive_comb(int step_val, int array_index)
{
    cout << "---" << endl;
    for (int i = array_index; i < set.size(); i++){
        onePossible.push_back(set[i]);
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < onePossible.size(); j++){
            sum += onePossible[j];
            if (step_val < 0){
                onePossible = {};
            }
        }
        cout << "Adding " << sum << " to allPossible" << endl;
        allPossible.push_back(sum);
        recursive_comb(step_val - 1, i + 1);
    }
}
```

And my main function looks like this:

```
int main(){
    recursive_comb(set.size() - 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < allPossible.size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < allPossible.size; j++){
            if (allPossible[i] == allPossible[j]){
                cout << "There is are two possible combinations that are alike << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when my onePossible is emptied, it doesn't empty at all. I have also tried emptying it at every point in the for loop, but that doesn't really work either, the numbers are just added to the allPossible like this:

```
[2], [2], [3], [4] //etc......
```

And what I want is this:

```
[2], [2], [3], [4], [2+2=4], [2+3=5], [2+4=6], [3+4=7] //not including all the repeating ones i might get.
```

So my actual question is:

How do I get all the possible sums for a vector ([1], [2], [1] + [2], etc) ?

Thank you for any answer you might provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PicklingTools](http://www.picklingtools.com/) distribution, there is a class which will compute all combinations.

```
// Compute all combinations of n choose k.  This computes all n choose
// k of combinations of the distinct integers 1..n.  Note that the
// permutations are permuted in sorted order. Other data can be
// "combinated" by using the numbers here as indicies into an array.

// // Typical usage
// #include "occombinations.h"
{
   Combinations c(n,k);
   do {
     int* cur = c.currentCombination();
     printCurrentCombination(cur, n, k);
   }  while (c.nextCombination());
}
```

What it returns is a list of indices which you can use to permute your vector:

```
  Combinations c(n,k);
  do {
     int *cur = c.currentCombination(); 

     int sum = 0;
     for (int ii=0; ii<k; ii++) {
        sum += vec[cur[ii]-1];  // Notice the extra indirection
     }
     if (sum==match_sum) { .. do something .. }
  } while (c.nextCombination());
```

The combinations class gives one based combinations, so notice the extra -1.
All 5 choose 2 combinations it would give are:

```
n = 5 k = 2
(1 2)
(1 3)
(1 4)
(1 5)
(2 3)
(2 4)
(2 5)
(3 4)
(3 5)
(4 5)
```

EDIT: the combinations generator is modelled after the permutations generator from the C++ STL.  The actual code file for the combinations is fairly standalone: you could probably pull out the "occombinations.h" out of the PicklingTools distribution (it's under C++/opencontainers_1_8_2/include) and use it without needing the whole distribution.